# regex to ensure a user entered url string contains proper https format

Tags: regex

Looking for a regex that detects if the user has entered in https://

and obviously allows the rest of the url string to be entered...

So user can enter in anything they want after the https:// but I need to make sure they enter https://
it cant be http:// or ftp:// has to be https://

Thanks

Comment: Please rewrite your question to make it more clear. What language tool do you use?

Comment: If you will permit anything after `https://`, you could just use a `left()` or `substring()` function for whatever language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this form of the URL worked

```
https://.*
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as "https://" in whatever language you're using.

For example, in python

```
import re 

match = re.match("https:\/\/",example_string)
if match:
   #code
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, issue is I don't control the behind the scenes code, its a CMS that is allowing us to enter in the regex pattern/html5 pattern so I don't have access to modify the code as in your example.

So I need it in a format that has no lines of code (ie. nothing code specific like php or python), it would be a simple regex.

So for example.. https:\/\/ but this doesnt work as its not accepting the rest of the url string.
Does that make a bit more sense?

Here are some example of what I mean: http://html5pattern.com/Miscs

Thanks

Comment: "https:\/\/.*" will work then as a regex to make sure that the url is https

Comment: Sorry but in the present case, you don't need to escape slashes :). And when you need to use backslashes in python, don't forget to use them in a raw string.